# javascript slideshow starts in the middle of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a small plugin from the jQuery-JavaScript-Library called Innerfade that I got here

http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/

I used it here http://web2.gvgphotowebdesign.com/promo.html

It works fine in all browser except, as usual, in IE. It seems that when it comes to IE, the slideshow that I put in a div starts in the middle instead to the normal upper-left corner

Would you know the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `text-align` to `left` for `div#portfolio`.

Comment: hi Anriëtte Combrink, thnx for the help, I really appreciated it. You can see the results now here <http://web2.gvgphotowebdesign.com/promo.html>. it might not be perfect, maybe because of the border but I like the effect. I dunno how can I repay you. By the way I'm from Manila, Philippines, a newbie when it comes to programming. All the scripts that I'm using in my site are all from Dreamweaver, BannerzestPro and downloaded from the Internet. I hope you won't stop helping people. God Bless You.

Comment: It was really nothing, that's why you come to Stack Overflow, to get help. And don't fret about it, we all started out as newbies. Just keep on developing, you will improve with time.